# Stata Order Rows by Weekday

Tags: stata

I'm looking to order a small set of data by day of week, Monday - Sunday. I import data from Excel with headings date, weekday, then two numerical rows Taps and Journeys. Stata organises this collapse alphabetically. I know I probably need to create a variable that codes day of week (e.g. Monday = 1) but can't quite get the code right.

Would it be a simple `generate` then `recode`?

```
     +-----------------------------------+
     |       Day        Taps    Journeys |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |    Friday   11472.286   7886.7144 |
  2. |    Monday   11609.333        8054 |
  3. |  Saturday   8508.5713        6223 |
  4. |    Sunday        9204   6799.1665 |
  5. |  Thursday   13246.833    9286.833 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  6. |   Tuesday   12876.167    8947.833 |
  7. | Wednesday       12773      8979.5 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Stata has a function `dow()` to generate day of the week from Stata daily dates. Tell us about your dates to get precise advice on how to code. More generally, we can't comment on your code unless you show some.

Comment: My dates are formatted as %tdDD/NN/CCYY. I believe I wouild need to [tag:generate] a new variable for day-of-week that I could then use as the [tag:by] qualifier in a [tag:collapse]. Ultimately I want to reduce down a dataset such that I can plot a graph of mean Taps and Journeys across typical weeksdays.

Answer (score 0):

As commented `dow()` maps daily dates to days of the week, more precisely 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday). It is easy to tweak that sequence to start on Monday. 
Running this script should show some simple techniques. For `c(Weekdays)` and other useful little lists, see the output of `creturn list`. Summarizing other variables by days of the week is something you already know.

```
clear 
set obs 21 
gen ddate = mdy(3,28,2016) + _n 
format ddate %tdDD/NN/CCYY 

gen dow = dow(ddate) 
tokenize "`c(Weekdays)'" 

forval d = 1/7 { 
    local D = `d' - 1 
    label define dow `D' "``d''", modify 
} 

label val dow dow 

tab dow 

replace dow = 7 if dow == 0 
label define dow 7 "Sunday", modify 

tab dow
```